# Counter-Example of $G_{X+Y}=G_{X}.G_{Y}$ with discrete law

Tags: random-variables, generating-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. Let's denote $G_{X}$ and $G_{Y}$ their generating functions. We know that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then
$$
G_{X+Y}=G_{X}.G_{Y}
$$

However, we know the reciprocal is not true. ($X$ and $Y$ following a Cauchy's law is a counter-example.)

However, is there any known example on random variable with discrete values ?

Comment: See, for example, the [example given by @Did here](/a/916541) and the discussion in the comments.  Basically if $X$ and $Y$ takes sufficiently many values and the $X+Y$ doesn't then there are more variables than there are linear equations, so you can always change it a little to destroy independence.